# How to instantiate objects with polymorphism using Arduino

Tags: inheritance, arduino, polymorphism

I am trying to implement these classes using Arduino and have some difficult to instantiate this.

```
class Component{
private:
  String _name;
  int _pin;
public:
  Component(char* name, int pin){
    _name = name;
    _pin = pin;
  }
  Component(Component &comp){
    _name = comp.get_name();
    _pin = comp.get_pin();
  }

  String get_name(){ return _name; }
  int get_pin(){ return _pin; }

  void set_name(String value){ _name = value;}
  void set_pin(String value){ _pin = value;}

  virtual void routine() = 0;
};

class Led : public Component{
public:
  Led(char* name, int pin) : Component(name, pin) {}
  void routine(){
   /* virtual function implemented here*/
  }
};

Component *led = new Led("t_red", 11);
```

The error my compiler said is `expected initializer before ‘*’ token
 Component *led = new Led("t_red", 11);`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you actually implement the constructor of `Led`, or did you leave it out?

Comment: @Rakete1111 I leave it out. I thought Led could use the Component constructor.

Comment: The error message is a bit strange, but leaving out a constructor for Led *is* an error and you should fix it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Led` needs a constructor.

```
class Led : public Component {
    // ...
    Led(char* name, int pin) :
        Component(name, pin)
    {
    }
};
```